# How to define "a" predicate using rdflib.js

Tags: javascript, rdflib, turtle-rdf

I'm using [rdflib.js](https://github.com/linkeddata/rdflib.js/) library to generate RDF documents.
You can define a statement in following way:

```
let subject = rdf.sym(location + '#this');
let predicate = rdf.sym(DC('author'));
let object = rdf.sym(authorWebId);
statement = rdf.st(subject, predicate, object, chatDocument);
```

However, I couldn't find a way to define the "**a**" predicate (without quotes), i.e. I'd like to have such statement:

```
someSubject: a ldp:BasicContainer
```

How to define that with rdflib.js?

Answer (score 1):

You should un-tag this with "rdflib" as that refers to the Python toolkit of that name.

But anyway, try `RDF('type')` since turtle sytax 'a' is just a short form for rdf:type.